# Entire even functions of order 1 have infinitely many zeros?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $f$ be an entire even function of order 1 such that $f(0)\neq 0$. Does $f$ have infinitely many zeros?

Comment: If $f(z)$ has just finitely many zeros, there would be a polynomial $P(z)$ such that $f(z) / P(z)$ is entire and non-vanishing, hence equal to $\exp(g(z))$ for some $g(z)$ entire. For $f(z)$ to have order $1$, the only possibility is that $g(z)$ be a linear function. But then $f(z)$ cannot be even. The contradiction shows that your $f(z)$ has indeed infinitely many zeros (and that can be made quantitative: $\sum 1 / |\rho| = +\infty$ is divergent over these zeros taken with multiplicities).

Comment: Alternatively, $g(z)=f(\sqrt{z})$ is entire and has order $1/2$, so has infinitely many zeros if non-constant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Any even entire function $f$ can be written as $f(z)=g(\sqrt{z})$, where $g$
is entire. To prove this just consider the power series. If $f$ is or order $1$, then
$g$ is of order $1/2$ (also very easy). And every function of non-integral order
has infinitely many zeros. This follows from the Hadamard factorization theorem.
In fact this is a very special case of the Hadamard theorem: if $g$ has finitely
many zeros and finite order then $g(z)=e^{P(z)}Q(z)$, where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials.

In fact this shows that any even function with finitely many zeros must have even or infinite order, which generalizes your statement.